# Write HTML file with variables inserted?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate a HTML file with a generated random number each time the script is run. My `rawHTML` is clearly wrong, any advice on how to accomplish this?

makeHTML.js

```
fs = require('fs');
util = require('util');
writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

let rawHTML = '<html>
<body style="color: white; background: black; width: 512px;">
<script>
var ranNum = number;
document.write ("<br/>TestText: ", ranNum);
</script>
</body>
</html>';

fn = async () => { await writeFile('finalHTML.html', rawHTML); }

fn()
```

Comment: You aren't actually inserting `ranNum` inside your `rawHTML`, you are just inserting "ranNum" as text. I think if you change `rawHtml` to be a template string using backticks ``, and then inserting it using `var ranNum = ${number}`, it should insert the random number.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: as in `let rawHTML = \`<html>
<body style="color: white; background: black; width: 512px;"><br/>TestText: ${number}</body>
</html>\``

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may be over-thinking this.  Since you've already used server-side code to generate the number, you don't need client-side code to do anything at all.  Just put the number in your string.  For example:

```
let rawHTML = `<html><body style="color: white; background: black; width: 512px;"><br/>TestText: ${number}</body></html>`;
```

Comment: Ah yes, perfect thank you. I will credit you the answer once the time limit has expired.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient solution would be to render the files on send via a package (`pug`/`ejs`).

Example:

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

app.get('/path', function(req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + 'directry/example.ejs', { number }); // Render your EJS file with the number included
});
```

Then in your `example.ejs` file:

```html
<html>
<body style="color: white; background: black; width: 512px;">
    <!-- Some HTML code -->
    <div>TextTest: <%= number %></div> <!-- define your number -->
</body>
</html>
```

References:

- [express documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
- [EJS documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)